# install android 4.1

Tags: android, build, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i'm trying build and install android 4.1.1 for samsung galaxy nexus.
how i'm building:

```
repo sync
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch full_maguro-userdebug
make -j3
```

building successfuly complete, then installation:

```
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot erase cache
fastboot erase userdata
fastboot flashall
```

installation complete, but after rebooting android doesn't run, only showing google logo.

whats i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i'm find problem. i'm forgot install proprietary [drivers](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers). just download it and extract in work directory

Comment: if you have problem with camera - download binary images from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#magurojro03c, unzip system.img, mount it (./out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img system.img system.img.raw && sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img.raw /media/cdrom/), then see device/samsung/maguro/properietary-blobs.txt from missing driver and copy it with adb push

Comment: wrong link above, use https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#yakju